# ng-grid col.naam cellTemplate isnt working

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

This is part of the columnDefs array:

```
{field: 'naam', displayName: 'naam', cellTemplate: '<div>{{row.getProperty(col.naam)}}</div>', enableCellEdit: true}, 
{field: 'naam', displayName: 'naam', enableCellEdit: true},
```

First line is doing nothing. The second is working properly. Probably minor issue with the implementation?

```
columnDefs: [{field: 'show', displayName: 'show', enableCellEdit: false, cellTemplate: '<span class="ngCellText cursor-pointer" ng-click=navEdit(row.getProperty(\'naam\'),row.getProperty(\'crediteurnummer\'));>show</span>'},
        //{field: 'show', displayName: 'show', enableCellEdit: false, cellTemplate: '<span class="ngCellText cursor-pointer"><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"></span>'},
        {field: 'naam', displayName: 'naam', cellTemplate: '<div>{{row.getProperty(col.naam)}}</div>', enableCellEdit: true}, 
        {field: 'naam', displayName: 'naam', enableCellEdit: true}, 
        {field:'crediteurnummer', displayName:'crediteurnummer', enableCellEdit: true},
        {field:'plaatsnaam', displayName:'plaatsnaam', enableCellEdit: true},
        {field:'land', displayName:'land', enableCellEdit: true}],
        rowTemplate:'<div style="height: 100%; color: #428bca;" ><div ng-style="{ \'cursor\': row.cursor }" ng-repeat="col in renderedColumns" ng-class="col.colIndex()" class="ngCell ">' +
        '<div class="ngVerticalBar" ng-style="{height: rowHeight}" ng-class="{ ngVerticalBarVisible: !$last }"> </div>' +
        '<div ng-cell></div>' +
        '</div></div>'
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write you cellTemplate like this:

```
{field: 'naam', displayName: 'naam', cellTemplate: '<div>{{row.entity.naam}}</div>', enableCellEdit: true},
```

This should do the trick.